# Extract contact info from intent from contact associated with account trigger

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I created my custom account and there are contacts associated with the account to trigger the application. However, I do not know how to parse the intent I get. I am getting the following intent:
data = content://com.android.contacts/data/73

I checked there is no contact with such ID and no one field is associated with this value (I have inspected Contacts, Raw and Data tables)

What does 73 mean? How to get the desired contact?

```
<intent-filter android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.uz.avtobank.profile" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

according the the uri `content://com.android.contacts/data/73` this is a `dataUri`, which means you can access its data via:

```
Uri dataUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/73");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null, null, null, null);
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c); // will print this data row to the log
c.close();
```